# How to handle exception pop-up on Oracle forms during automation?

Tags: java, oracleforms, openscript

How to handle a Oracle Form Pop-up using java? I am automating Oracle Forms to create invoice using openscript. During the creation, a Oracle Form pop-up populates on the screen any point during run-time. 
try{} catch(Exception e){} didn't work. Though with popup on the page, the control doesn't enter catch block. It apparently fails to identify object on the next step.

Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Robot class for popup clicks if Tool Doesnt recognize.
It works on Ketboard operation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

```
 robot.delay(50);
 robot.type(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
```